# SQL Updating TImeStamp To Now()

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having my application checking the database for expired members.

I'm using:`UPDATE members SET enabled=0 WHERE now() >= time`

That runs every 30 seconds. It was first running at 10 seconds but I didn't know if that was an issue so I made it 30 seconds instead. That's the only thing I have running and my timestamp goes from the time I set and sets it to the time the SQL command is executed. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Have you read the question?

Comment: what is time? Column name?

Comment: @user3723271 Yes, I have, but I didn't understand. Could you provide some examples, please?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the expected result? You check the timestamp compared to now() (now() is always greater than time ) and you always update the field. The timestamp is updated also that' s why you get the execution time.

Comment: `WHERE now()` is greater or equal to `time`. Nowhere am I setting `time` or updating `time`. The `time` is the expiration date. The column name is 'time'. If `now()` is greater or equal to the expiration time, then it would disable them. So, no, it's not an expected result.

Comment: can you give us the members table definition?